# Calculate $P(A = \frac 34)$, given the PDF of $A$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

$A$ is absolutely continuous random variable. Given a density function $fa(a)$ I have to calculate $P(A = \frac 34)$.

I tried to just calculate the integral with both lower and upper limit $\frac 34$ and then $f(a)$ da but that just gives zero. What would be correct to do?

Comment: Why do you think $0$ is wrong?

Comment: It is the correct way to calculate it?

Comment: I would say it is, but technically it depends on your teacher. You could reason for it by saying that $P(A = 3/4) = P(3/4\leq A\leq 3/4)$, where the latter clearly justifies integrating the density function (or using the CDF), precicely because the distribution is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

If $dF/dx = f$ then
$$P(p \le X \le q) =\int_{p}^{q}f(x)\,dx=\left[F(x)\right]_{p}^{q}=F(q)-F(p)$$
If $p=q$ then this equals zero ($p=q=3/4$ in your case.)

For a discussion about the intuition behind this, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259928/how-to-explain-why-the-probability-of-a-continuous-random-variable-at-a-specific)