# Probability of a continuous random variable at a value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Why does $P(X=x)=0$ when $x$ is a continuous random variable? Apart from reasoning using integration, in terms of events how do we make sense of this? Why do we say a probability AT any value is zero?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the probability that a continuous random variable takes a specific value zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180283/why-is-the-probability-that-a-continuous-random-variable-takes-a-specific-value)

Comment: This one might also be valuable [How to explain why the probability of a continuous random variable at a specific value is 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259928/how-to-explain-why-the-probability-of-a-continuous-random-variable-at-a-specific)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ with distribution $\nu$ - that is, for each $E\in\mathcal F$, we have $\mathbb P(X\in E) = \nu(E)$. By definition, $X$ is *continuous* when there exists a measurable function $f$ which satisfies $\nu(E) = \int_E f\ \mathsf d\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$. Since the Lebesgue measure of a finite set is zero, it follows readily that $$\nu(\{0\})=\mathbb P(X=0) = \int_{\{0\}} f\ \mathsf d\lambda = 0.$$